# Как заставить работать событие в phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Создал событие. Каждый день ставить NULL в двух полях, почему-то не работает, где ошибка?

```
UPDATE `user_accounts` SET `restore_date` = NULL, `restore_key` = NULL WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - `restore_date` >= 172800
```

Comment: Что показывает такой запрос: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'event_scheduler'`?

Comment: event_scheduler
OFF, точно, в my.ini нужно включить) спасибо!